# Using htaccess to rewrite get requests, results same - case insensitive

Tags: .htaccess

I am using htaccess to rewrite get requests to a directory, these requests are unique URL tokens, I am for some reason getting the same page if I alter the case. What's going on? Is there anything other than the standard rewrite cond and rule? It essential that my urls are case sensitive.

I am using Apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, my rewrite rules are:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ content.php?query=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What are your rules and what are you trying to do? Are you using apache? nginx? iis?

Comment: @JonLin Ok, I have added the info, please take a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was not a `.htaccess` problem, rather an isssue with MySQL, I had set all my url columns to varchar, varchar is case-insensitive, it is important to set as blob for case-sensitive items such as passwords and keys.